# Grafana worldmap panel: latitude and longitude in mysql cannot display points on map

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, grafana

I am using a worldmap panel on Grafana v5.4.2, my data source is a mysql database, and there I have some ip address, city and location string with latitude and longitude, I would like to display the city name of the ip addresses, the value would be the ip address count belongs to a city, the following is my sql:

```
SELECT
    any_value(city.city) as metric,
    count(ip.loc) as value,
    CAST(substring(ip.loc, 1, INSTR(ip.loc, “,”) - 1) AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as latitude,
    CAST(substring(ip.loc, INSTR(ip.loc, “,”) + 1) AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as longitude,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) as time_sec
FROM ip
    inner join city on city.ctid = ip.ctid
WHERE ip.iptype & 2
group by ip.loc
```

I can get response with the sql query, the response is something like the following, but nothing display on the map:

```
xhrStatus:“complete”
request:Object
method:“POST”
url:“api/tsdb/query”
data:Object
from:“1541896435220”
to:“1547534884686”
queries:Array[1]
response:Object
results:Object
A:Object
refId:“A”
meta:Object
series:Array[516]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
    name:“巴西 巴西 value”
    points:Array[1]
        0:Array[1,1547534884000]
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
```

…

the following is the ruling result from mysql:
±--------±-------±----------±-----------±----------+
| metric | value | latitude | longitude | time_sec |
±--------±-------±----------±-----------±----------+
| 巴西 巴西 | 1 | -14.242900 | -54.387798 | 1547535460 |
| 巴西 圣保罗州 圣保罗 | 1 | -23.550520 | -46.633309 | 1547535460 |
| 新加坡 新加坡 | 16 | 1.352083 | 103.819836 | 1547535460 |
| 越南 越南 | 1 | 10.768451 | 106.694363 | 1547535460 |
| 柬埔寨 柬埔寨 | 7 | 12.547730 | 104.983856 | 1547535460 |
…

can anyone address me what’s going on?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your contribution helped me with WorldMap.
and I will try to help you with your problem (Unfortunately, it is still not perfect as there is "n/a" display when mouse hit the points).

First: My sourcedata from Postgresql. I have one tables where i keep coordinates
[Coordinates Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtMje.jpg)

Second: My sql query is:
[SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTgWS.jpg) and result from query: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYG1V.jpg)

Third: My worldmap Settings
[worldmap settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwMAk.jpg)

FINALe: Working worldmap 
[REsULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZJKg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the "Format as" to "Table", and remove the "metric" from my sql, it prints point on the map.
Unfortunately, it is still not perfect as there is "n/a" display when mouse hit the points, I expecting something like city name, that's why I put the city as metric...need more investigation...